# PHP: I’m not able to save image from remote url

Tags: php, curl, gd, fopen, file-get-contents

I need to read an image from a remote url, and then save it on my hosting webspace.

This is the image that I'd like to save (it's a webcam test): **http://remoteimage.ddns.info:17000/snapshot.cgi**

As you can see, if you put the image url in a browser then you can see the image properly. But if I try to save the image by using a php script, nothing happens. I've tried three different php scripts, but none of them works.

Some more notes:

- php version 5.3.29,
- "allow_url_fopen" is set to "on",
- if I use a different image url (eg: google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png), all the scripts work fine.

*Can anyone help me on how to save this remote image with a php script?*

Here are the three scripts that I've tested so far with no result.

**Script 1 - using file_get_contents:**

```
$remoteUrl = "http://remoteimage.ddns.info:17000/snapshot.cgi";
$image = file_get_contents($remoteUrl); 
$fileName = "captured-image.jpg";
file_put_contents($fileName, $image);
```

With the above script I get this warning:
file_get_contents(url): failed to open stream: Connection refused on line 2

**Script 2 – using GD functions:**

```
$remoteUrl = "http://remoteimage.ddns.info:17000/snapshot.cgi";
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($remoteUrl);
$fileName = "captured-image.jpg";
$quality = 90;
imagejpeg($image, $fileName, $quality);
```

With the above script I get again the same warning:
file_get_contents(url): failed to open stream: Connection refused on line 2

**Script 3 – using curl:**

```
$remoteUrl = "http://remoteimage.ddns.info:17000/snapshot.cgi";

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 20;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $remoteUrl);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$image = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$fileName = "captured-image.jpg";
file_put_contents($fileName, $image);
```

In this case I get no warning, but in the end I get an empty image file.

Comment: Perhaps the website simply won't allow it?

Comment: cURL should do the trick. Have you tried setting an UserAgent in the options?

Comment: @D4V1D: no I haven't tried setting a User Agent. How do I do it?

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);`

Comment: @D4V1D: I've tried the curl script with this user agent, but the script still doesn't work, I get an ampty image.
    $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)';

Comment: @Epodax: it is a strange situation. I can access the image from the browser, but I cannot through php.

Comment: The site can allow users to view it but block scripts / php from fetching it.

Comment: The problem is probably the chunked encoding, not some server blocking. Try wget, this works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the response headers:

```
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Mon, 08 Jun 2015 08:57:40 GMT
Server:lighttpd/1.4.31
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

`Transfer-Encoding:chunked` means that the content is (or could be) streamed. This is a HTTP 1.1 standard. Are you using an older PHP version (<5.3)?

I tried with this script which works on my machine (PHP 5.6.2, OSX).

```
<?php
$rCURL = curl_init();
curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://remoteimage.ddns.info:17000/snapshot.cgi');
curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$aData = curl_exec($rCURL);
curl_close($rCURL);
file_put_contents('bla.jpeg', $aData);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Aebersold. My php version is 5.3.29
I tried your script, but it doesn't work on my server. I still get an empty image file as result.
What else could I try?

Comment: Probably your version does not support HTTP/1.1 or chunked encoding. I would update PHP to a more recent version, 5.3 is end of life anyway. Alternatively you could use `wget` (although this is not PHP). I tried fetching the image with wget, which works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over php version because I'm just a customer of a shared hosting. By the way, I've run phpinfo and I've found  **_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]: HTTP/1.1** . _Is there a way to use the `wget` command with php? What command string have you used in your test?_